# Trying to trigger a WheelEvent programmatically with Hammerjs

Tags: reactjs, mousewheel, hammer.js

I am using a library (https://github.com/asmyshlyaev177/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu) that scrolls on use of the mousewheel, and I want to use this functionality when swiping left or right.

I am using hammerjs to replicate swipeleft and swiperight behavior, and this is working.

However, creating a WheelEvent does not seem to trigger the functionality dependent on the WheelEvent.

I am using componentDidUpdate for now as my react lifecycle method because for some reason `this.containerRef.current` is always null in componentDidMount, but once I figure out the reason behind that, I'll probably move it.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if(this.containerRef.current !== null) {
    this.hammer = Hammer(this.containerRef.current)
    this.hammer.on('swiperight', () => alert("swipe right"));
    var wheelevent = new WheelEvent("wheel", {deltaX: 500, deltaY: 500});
    this.hammer.on('swiperight', () => window.dispatchEvent(wheelevent));
    }
}
```

Now I want to point out, the alert for swipe right DOES happen, so the behavior is definitely triggering, however my WheelEvent is not being caught by the scroll library.

How should I trigger a WheelEvent programmatically?

EDIT - I made a codepen about it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-fi7tv

Comment: Instead of using `window.dispatchEvent` try using `element.dispatchEvent`. You will do this to your container element which is listening for the wheel. Probably `this.containerRef.current.dispatchEvent`

Comment: Moving the hammer initializing code to `componentDidMount` does work for me, and the scroll event is also logged properly, [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-9u77n).

Comment: @MunimMunna - I believe you shared my old code, as the link you shared does not have componentDidMount in it

Comment: Also on my phone your current code also worked?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - when the swipe right and swipe left events are firing, I am not seeing the items scroll

Comment: For me even the items are scrolling

Comment: My bad, I have updated the sandbox code, for me it works as well.

Comment: Are you both unchecking "dragging"? I have done so - I am continually triggering the "swipe right" and "swipe left" actions, and nothing is happening for me.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, now I am able to reproduce the issue, you missed an important point there :-)

Comment: @TarunLalwani - sorry about that! I used the example from the library writer and only added my code to it and didn't think that people wouldn't disable dragging. I edited the sample code in my question to disable dragging!

Comment: Why are you disabling dragging? it is disabling touch events, as docs say, "dragging: Allow drag items by mouse(and touch)".

Comment: @MunimMunna Because dragging via touch is very, very slow - like VERY slow. It is leading to very bad UX. The mouse wheel is very fast and operates how I want touch to operate. I intend to replicate the mouse wheel functionality which has the exact behavior I want programmatically, with swiping behaviors via HammerJS. I am absolutely certain that this is the behavior that I want, and that I do not want to use the library's dragging ability.

Comment: Try dragging via touch, and then test out using the mouse wheel. You will see a vastly different experience.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, see if this does the job? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-j46l8

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes! That seems to do exactly what I want! Thank you. Please write a formal answer and I'll accept it and award the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is that issue is related to `Dragging` being disabled and the event is canceled.

So you need to send the event down the chain a bit. I have updated the codesandbox below which works

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-j46l8

The updated code part is below

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-wrapper")[0];
this.hammer.on("swiperight", () => elem.dispatchEvent(wheeleventRight));
this.hammer.on("swipeleft", () => elem.dispatchEvent(wheeleventLeft));
```

You may want to better the approach though in a more reactive fashion later. But this does show that once you sent the event in lower order elements the wheeling does work well